# How to disallow URLs in Robots.txt that DO NOT end with a certain characters

Tags: seo, robots.txt, technical-seo

My website has 2 types of URLs

1. URLs that end with `.html` ->  `example.com/example.html`
2. URLs that do not end with `.html` -> `example.com/example`

The `.html` version is the version I want to be indexed. The non `.html` version is auto generated by the CMS and there is nothing I can do about it technically. I can't noindex the URLs that do not end with `.html`

That's why I want to block access to URLs that do not end with `.html`

I know that `Disallow: /*.html$` will block all URLs ending with `.html`. The question is how do I do the opposite?

How do I block all URLs that DO NOT end with `.html`?

Is there another solution expect `robots.txt`?

Comment: If the non **html** versions have identical urls with html, then you should redirect them.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you don't disallow these pages. Disallowing duplicates is not the best practice.

You have [rel canonical](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/consolidate-duplicate-urls) for it. And your task is trivial from the point of the canonical.

A better solution here, however, would be [redirecting](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/consolidate-duplicate-urls#redirects-method) to the html version of the page from a non-html version.

It's also worth to say that it's quite debatable whether it makes sense to add non-contributing characters to the url. I prefer Occam's Razor approach where if something doesn't add value in the url, it shouldn't be there, so I would be setting up the redirections the other way around: from .html to the clear url.